# Display Data from Two Tables but the 2nd Table has more Data than the 1st One

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Good Afternoon.

I have two Tables in MySQL and they are.

Table 1: purchorder

```
+-----------+------------------------+----------+
| ItemCode  | Description            | OrderQty |
+-----------+------------------------+----------+
| HKQSLUWKN | 1 Computer Set DDR3    | 30.00    |
| SORHFRBPJ | Operations Logs System | 40.00    |
| OP8XMREC0 | 12 Ream Bond Paper     | 50.00    |
| CPD5CGDZ3 | Ajinomoto Seasoning    | 60.00    |
+-----------+------------------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table 2: receiving

```
+-----------+------------------------+---------+---------+
| ItemCode  | Description            | QtyPack | QtyStan |
+-----------+------------------------+---------+---------+
| HKQSLUWKN | 1 Computer Set DDR3    | 5.00    | 4.00    |
| SORHFRBPJ | Operations Logs System | 40.00   | 0.00    |
| HKQSLUWKN | 1 Computer Set DDR3    | 24.96   | 0.00    |
| OP8XMREC0 | 12 Ream Bond Paper     | 50.00   | 0.00    |
| CPD5CGDZ3 | Ajinomoto Seasoning    | 60.00   | 0.00    |
+-----------+------------------------+---------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My Question is How can I display this 2 tables together like this?

[Please See the Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXK2c.png)

You know, Display the Data from `Table: purchorder` in the Left Side together with the data from `Table: receiving` in the Right but my problem here is the Data from `Table: receiving` has 2 more and it will be possible happen to other data`s also (**Please check the Image above**)

I will be using the Criteria of `purchorder.ItemCode=receiving.ItemCode` and `purchorder.PONO = 'PO787HZN'`

Here is the Possible Output that I need and If this will not work in Database is it Possible to work on VB.Net Datagridview?

[Please See the Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STFLo.png)

TYSM for future help and I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use join

Inner join if all the itemCode match

```
select a.*, b.* 
from table1 as a 
inner join table2 as b on a.ItemCode = b.ItemCode  ;
```

Left join if not all the itemCode match

```
select a.*, b.* 
from table1 as a 
left join table2 as b on a.ItemCode = b.ItemCode  ;
```

Comment: TYSM for the Fast Help, Is it possible to that the Data from the left would not be repeat if the it has double data from the 2nd table?

Comment: Yes but show an example (update your question) so .i  can undetsand better

Comment: yes sir I will Update It by providing another Image Example

Comment: Sir Please see the Updated Post

Comment: The sample you provided can not be done with  a query  if you need that layout  must format the result of the query with a proper page formatter tool or language ..eg. in web you can work server side in php and render the the result in  html

Comment: I get your point now Sir, Im currently using VB.Net and I want to Display this in Datagridview any way sir Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can use VB.net for format the rsult but this is another question .

Comment: I dont want to repost this question sir because it might be marked as duplicate so I updated the post and added VB.Net and Datagridview in the Tag

Comment: @NyxAssasin  ..a few suggestion   In stackoverflow is not fair change a question or use the same question  for more then an answer .. if you sue the same question  and this question have already answer .. the SO user are less interessed to evaluete the question .. so don't worry for question duplicate .. the better way is rate this question as youy prefer  and post a new question with the result of this but the new part cleary exposed ..

Comment: Noted on that Sir TYSM

Answer (score 1):

Just try `JOIN`:

```
select p.*, r.*
from purchorder p
join receiving r on p.ItemCode= r.ItemCode
order by p.ItemCode
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d237b/2)

Comment: TYSM for the Fast Help, Is it possible to that the Data from the left would not be repeat if the it has double data from the 2nd table?

Comment: @NyxAssasin It is possible, but just meaningless.

Comment: The one you saying sir is the output that I need Sir. :(

Comment: Sir Please see the Updated Post